# sum hours and minutes in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I am searching an easy way to sum hours and minutes in javascript to produce a total value :

```
var json1 = {
  hour : "8",
  minutes : "15"
};

var json2 = {
  hour : "8",
  minutes : "45"
};
```

Expected output :

```
var total = "17h00";
```

Comment: take a look at momentjs http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/add/

Comment: @dubes, I know it is *very* trendy to suggest `moment.js` for everything even remotely related to dates, but I don't think it is really necessary here.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It does not look like a js problem right now, but more like a math problem.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I gave that advice not because it was trendy, but just in case it helps. It is very rare that you only have that one problem in your codebase for which you are asking for help. If he is handling dates, moment can help a lot. As with all advice, it is free to be given and equally free to be rejected if it does not meet your need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var totalH;
var totalM;

addTimes = function(timeMap) {

    // First simply adding all of it together, total hours and total minutes
    for (var x in timeMap) {
        totalH += parseInt(timeMap[x].hour, 10);
        totalM += parseInt(timeMap[x].minutes, 10);
    }

    // If the minutes exceed 60
    if (totalM >= 60) {
        // Divide minutes by 60 and add result to hours
        totalH += Math.floor(totalM / 60);
        // Add remainder of totalM / 60 to minutes
        totalM = totalM % 60;
    }

    return totalH + "h" + totalM;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `parseInt` without the radix, since it would seem that a leading `0` could be a good possibility here, and older implementations will interpret that as octal.

Comment: Could you please provide an update of your code if in entry i have a map of json objects. (I don't know in advance, how many objects i have in entry...)

Comment: @wawanopoulos What would happen if the amount of hours exceeds 24h? Would it go back to 00h00 or would it become 1d00h00?

Comment: i would like to get the total sum in hours and minutes. (not in day). It could be (1200h45min) for example

Comment: Very nice observation by squint, adding the radix to parseInt to make sure it's looking for decimal values. Cheers

Comment: I think there is a bug in the code. I have 2 json in entries with hour = 9 and minutes = 15 for each object. The result should be 18h30. I get 18h60..

Comment: You're right, I've edited the code, please try the new solution.

Comment: @TomNijs I think that there is yet a bug. I get a sum of 44h90 ! It should be 45h30 because min stops to 60...

Comment: Apologies @wawanopoulos I had written this freehand without testing it, the last check to see if minutes exceed 60 had a "<" instead of the required ">". Should work now.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy paste in chrome console and see the pretty result

```
var json1 = { hour : "8", minutes : "15" };
var json2 = { hour : "8", minutes : "45" };

function get_add_two_times(json1, json2) {
    hr            = parseInt(json1.hour) + parseInt(json2.hour); 
    mn            = parseInt(json1.minutes) + parseInt(json2.minutes);
    final_hr      = hr + Math.floor(mn/60);
    final_mn      = mn%60;
    final_mn      = (final_mn < 10) ? '0' + final_mn : final_mn;

    return final_hr + 'h' + final_mn;
}
get_add_two_times(json1,json2);
```

Some sample outputs

```
var json1 = {hour : "1", minutes : "15"};
var json2 = {hour : "02", minutes : "49"};
> "4h04"

var json1 = {hour : "12", minutes : "15"};
var json2 = {hour : "12", minutes : "49"};
> "25h04"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a functional approach, assuming you have an array of times

```
var times = [{
  hour : "8",
  minutes : "15"
},{
  hour : "8",
  minutes : "45"
}]
```

Iterate over the times, summing, then formatting, then joining to a string.

```
times.reduce(function(memo, t) { // sum the times
  memo[0] += parseInt(t.hour, 10)
  memo[1] += parseInt(t.minutes, 10)
  if (memo[1] >= 60) {
    memo[0] += ~~(memo[1]/60)
    memo[1] = memo[1] % 60
  }
  return memo
}, [0, 0]).map(function(t) { // map to the desired format
  if (t < 10) {
    return '0' + t
  }
  return t
}).join('h')  // => 17h00
```

Comment: Could you please update your code if in entry i have a map of objects instead of an array

Comment: @wawanopoulos what do you mean "a map of objects"? An object whose values are the times? Provide a valid JS structure and I can help.